# readyState vs status==200

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
    {
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
```

Above code is from:http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp.

Question:

According to this tutorial:

```
readyState: 4: request finished and response is ready 

status: 200: "OK" 

When readyState is 4 and status is 200, the response is ready:
```

since when `xmlhttp.readyState == 4`,  response is ready, why do we still need `xmlhttp.status == 200`? what is the difference between `xmlhttp.readyState == 4` and `xmlhttp.status == 200`?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The status of the response, `xhr.status`, is (generally) used to determine whether the request was successful or not.  `xhr.readyState` is simply used to determine the state of the request, such as "has not yet been sent" (0), "complete and response received" (4), etc.

The server is responsible for providing the `status`, while the user agent provides the `readyState`.

Comment: exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 26):

status indicates if server response is ok.
In general words, when you got an status

> **500 - 599:** the server had an error
>
> **400 - 499:** this is a client error (Ex: 404 page not found)
>
> **300 - 399:** then exists a redirect
>
> **200 - 299:** then it is correct and
>
> **100 - 199:** means information message

Then the status==200 is getting you a message where the server says: 'Hey man I do the work!'

Answer (score 23):

my analogy : An ambulance carrying a patient is going to a hospital.In this scenario family(client) and hospital (server) needs to keep track of two things

- Ambulance reached hospital successfully.(`readyState`)
- Health updates of patient during this process.(`status`)

If `readyState === 4` and `status === 200`, means everything is all right.In the same way ajax call works.

Comment: Nice explanatiuon.

Answer (score 13):

readyState  Holds the status of the XMLHttpRequest. Changes from 0 to 4:

> 0: request not initialized
>
> 1: server connection established
>
> 2: request received
>
> 3: processing request
>
> 4: request finished and response is ready
>   status      200: "OK"
>               404: Page not found

Answer (score 3):

Consider you have an error on your server side code. You request the page, and the readyState will be 4 when the server finishes streaming the response, but the status code will be 500 (or 500-something).

Answer (score 3):

***readyState*  Holds the status of the XMLHttpRequest.**

0: request not initialized

1: server connection established

2: request received

3: processing request

4: request finished and response is ready

***status*  Returns the status-number of a request**

200: "OK"

403: "Forbidden"

404: "Not Found"

for details of response messages
visit

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmessages.asp

Answer (score 1):

The `readyState` refers to the response of the request - it is 4 when you have finished retrieving the response and there is something to look at. The actual value is still not known, so you need to check the `status` that has been returned.

Answer (score 0):

onreadystatechange=function() executes only when we get the response from the server.
If we get response from the server means our request is finished which is indicated by 4.And 200 tells us its status that is correct.
"4: request finished and response is ready status 200"
We get status 404 if the page is not found.

Answer (score 0):

Illustration:
You (client) send a package to your girlfriend (server), but requires her signature (200 - signed or 404 - not signed). You can check the status of your package (0 - at post office, 4 - out for delivery). Once the package leaves the facility, it will be marked out for delivery (4). But if your girlfriend is not at home when the package arrives, it will return to the post office as not signed (404).

So, it is possible for a status to be received regarding the package (4) and a status of whether delivery was successful (404). With AJAX, a request can be made to a server. Once the requested information has been obtained (this includes the status of the server - whether the data/document was found), then it is sent back to the receiver (client) for analysis, prior to displaying any content.