# Count in txt is reset because of xmlhttp.send(NULL);!

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have the following code:

index.html

```
function MakeRequest()
{
   var xmlHttp = getXMLHttp();
   xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function()
   {
     if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
     {
       HandleResponse(xmlHttp.responseText);
     }
     else{HandleResponse(xmlHttp.responseText);}
   }
    xmlHttp.open("GET", "compteur.php", true);
   xmlHttp.send(null);
 }

function HandleResponse(response)
{
  document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = response;
}   


<span id="space" ><input onclick="MakeRequest();" type="button" value="PUSH"      id="bouton"/></span>

<div id="text" >0</div>
```

count.php:

```
<?php

 $fp = false;
 // Open file for reading, then writing
 while ( ($fp=fopen('nombre.txt','r+'))===false ) {
     usleep(250000); // Delay 1/4 second
 }
 // Obtain lock
 while ( !flock($fp, LOCK_EX) ) {    
     usleep(250000); // Delay 1/4 second
 }
 // Read Clicks
 $clicks = trim(fread($fp,1024));
 // Add click
 $clicks++;
 // Empty file
 ftruncate($fp,0);
 // Write clicks
 fwrite($fp, $clicks);
 // Release Lock
 flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
 // Release handle
 fclose($fp);

 echo $clicks;

 ?>
```

The code functions. Each time the button is pushed, the MakeRequest function is called and increments the count in the txt file thanks to the count.php function.

My problem is that when the count is written in the txt file, NULL is also written every time before the count, and when there are too many NULL, the count goes to line 2 of the txt file and comes back to "1".

I think the problem lies in the  xmlHttp.send(null); 
I tried several solutions including xmlHttp.send(); but then my code stops functionninng !!!

What I mean, is that instead of writing "2" in the txt file when button is clicked and then "3" when it's clicked again, it writes "NULL 2" ans then "NULL NULL 3". How to avois this ?

One good example of the consequence of this is this : my count went up to 380 and then to 1 and stopped increasing!

How can I be sure that my count won't be reset to "1" suddenly at a point or another ?

Comment: first of all it is not because of `send(null)`.

Comment: what is your desired output and why you want such output? I asked that because I think it would be better ways to do that.

Comment: What I mean, is that instead ow writing "2" in the txt file when button is clicked and then "3" when it's clicked again, it writes "NULL 2" ans then "NULL NULL 3". How to avois this ?

Comment: why you have added `ftruncate($fp,0);`? please remove it and try it again.

Comment: ftruncate($fp,0); is necessary. If you dont put it, it makes 1, and then 12, and then 123 as your count. It puts your counts next to echother thhus increasing it strangely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So now I get what you want your prbolem is because of fopen mode. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

I think this code should work.

```
<?php

 $fp = false;
 // Open file for reading, then writing
 while ( ($fp=fopen('nombre.txt','r+'))===false ) {
     usleep(250000); // Delay 1/4 second
 }
 // Obtain lock
 while ( !flock($fp, LOCK_EX) ) {    
     usleep(250000); // Delay 1/4 second
 }
 // set pointer to begining of file
 fseek($fp,0);
 // Read Clicks
 $clicks = trim(fread($fp,1024));
 // Add click
 $clicks++;
 // Empty file
 ftruncate($fp,0);
 // set pointer to begining of file
 fseek($fp,0);
 // Write clicks
 fwrite($fp, $clicks);
 // Release Lock
 flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
 // Release handle
 fclose($fp);

 echo '|'.$clicks.'|';

 ?>
```

Comment: IT WORKS ! THANK U SO MUCH! Now I hope my count will never go back suddenly to 1! P.S.: I removed the vertical strokes around count, they were also printed and i just want the value!

Answer (score 1):

I generally recommend that people use a framework for AJAX (i.e. jQuery) because it avoids the nuts and bolts problems like this (in other words it's one less point of failure for your code).

You probably need to have a status check in your code as well

```
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function()
   {
     if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status==200)
     {
       HandleResponse(xmlHttp.responseText);
     }
     else{HandleResponse(xmlHttp.responseText);}
   }
```

This is discussed in more detail in this thread [readyState vs status==200](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17561463/2370483)

Comment: +1 because of good point. But -1 because I think its not about -user3601940's- question. so 1-1=0

Comment: I am not sure thsi is what I need but thx in anyway... It looks like it ads more security.