# Refresh JS script value every second

Tags: javascript, json

I have a script which is a getting value "average" from JSON array

```
<p id="ticker"></p>


<script>
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
  myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
  document.getElementById("ticker").innerHTML = myObj.average; };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://bitbay.net/API/Public/BTC/ticker.json", true);
  xmlhttp.send();
</script>
```

My problem is making this `<p>` refresh every some seconds. I wasted all day to do this. Could you please help me with it?

Comment: setIntervar(functionName,timeInMilliseconds) . Write that function inside setInterval.

Comment: Could you simply wrap the entire script in a `setInterval(function() { //SCRIPT }, 1000);` ?  *(1000 = 1 second. Change to fit your need.)*

Comment: @blr, see [my updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44570752/4222181) to find out how to get rid of `parse` exception.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do this:

```
<script>
window.setInterval(function(){
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
  myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
  document.getElementById("ticker").innerHTML = myObj.average; };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://bitbay.net/API/Public/BTC/ticker.json", true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}, 1000);
</script>
```

This runs your "function" every second (1000 milliseconds). I advice you to throw this into another function making it more like:

```
<script>
window.setInterval(updateTicker(), 1000);

function updateTicker(){
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        document.getElementById("ticker").innerHTML = myObj.average; 
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://bitbay.net/API/Public/BTC/ticker.json", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `setInterval(()=>{//code }, time)` to repeat getting the JSON.

```js
setInterval(getAvg, 5*1000); // every 5 seconds

function getAvg() {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    document.getElementById("ticker").innerHTML = myObj.average; 
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://bitbay.net/API/Public/BTC/ticker.json", true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

```html
<p id="ticker"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple setInterval should do the trick.

```
<p id="ticker"></p>

<script>  
  var ticker = document.getElementById("ticker");  // Cache that (faster)

  function updateP(){
     //... Do whatever
     ticker.innerHTML = "..."
  }

  updateP(); // Update once immediately...
  setInterval(updateP, 3000) // ...and then again every 3000ms
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`setInterval()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) (which calls a function or evaluates an expression at specified intervals in milliseconds) to achieve this:

```js
function getValue(){
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
        var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText); 
        document.getElementById("ticker").innerHTML = myObj.average; 
    }  
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://bitbay.net/API/Public/BTC/ticker.json", true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}

setInterval(getValue, 1000);
```

```html
<p id="ticker"></p>
```

**UPDATE:** to fix the `parse` exception we should [process the response only if the request was successful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17561463/readystate-vs-status-200).

Answer (score -2):

```
<p>Click the button to wait 3 seconds, then alert "Hello".</p>
<p id="text">After clicking text will change here and count starts for every 0.5 seconds. This goes on forever...</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
var i=0;
function myFunction() {

    setInterval(function(){ document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = i++; }, 500);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you only show examples at least explain what part does what

Comment: @LucaKiebel I've added comment for this question I think you didn't see that.

Comment: then you should at least have quoted yourself.