# Ajax Vanilla JS - ajax async continuing without waiting for readyState 4, status 200

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

**TLDR:** I would like to wait for the 1st request to be done, before continuing to the 2cnd etc.

---

Hello,

I am currently working on a HotSpot page. The user needs to input his email, and Voila! he gets internet access.

The thing that is *SUPPOSED* to happen in the background, is that when the user inserts his email and presses send;

1. an AJAX async POST is made to the router, with username and password,

then the js/html page waits for the readyState === 4 (DONE) response from the router,

2. an AJAX async POST is made to a server on a different network (which requires the user to have internet connection), which sends the users email,

then the js/html page waits for the DONE response

3. the user is redirected.

Thats basically what should happen. What is actually happening, is that the JS does not wait for the readyState === 4 and Status === 200. Once the user clicks Submit, he is redirected right away.

I can't use JQuery, as the router (Mikrotik) is using $ for it's own purpose.

After inspecting the network with the F12 tool, I can see that the POST to router has a status of 200, and is carrying the correct Parameters (username=HSuser&password=SimpleUserPassword) and I can see that the POST to the server has a status of 200 and also has the correct Parameters (email address ie: Email=Ba%40loo.ns).

I guess my JS code is somehow wrong, as it does not wait.

Also, for some reson after fiddling with the code, no more emails are inserted into the Database (they were before, don't know what the is problem now.)

Below is the current code. I'll also post a previous version (which also didn't work) in case someone can spot the problem there.

In case anyone requires any additional information, let me know.

Thank you.

---

*Edit 3.*:

I continued to read Stack Overflow and I've stumbled onto this [piece of information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17561463/readystate-vs-status-200?rq=1)...

> The server is responsible for providing the `status`, while the user agent provides the `readyState`.

Is this done server side automatically, or do I need to implement it somehow?

---

**Edit 1.**:

I tried console log here

```
                if (xhr.readyState === DONE){

                    console.log("XHR1" + xhr.readyState);
                    console.log("XHR1" + xhr.status);

                    if (xhr.status === OK){
```

and here

```
                            if (xhr2.readyState === DONE){

                                console.log("XHR2" + xhr2.readyState);
                                console.log("XHR2" + xhr2.status);

                                if (xhr2.status === OK){
```

and I only got *XHR1* (XHR14 and XHR1200), I didn't get anything from *XHR2*.

---

**Edit 2.**:

Tried replacing onreadystatechange with onload, still does the same thing.

---

*Current HTML code:*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html" />
<meta charset="utf-8" />

<title>HotSpot</title>

</head>
<body>

    <!-- Email form which is saved into the DB -->
    <form accept-charset="utf-8" name="mail" onsubmit="return false;" method="post" id="mail">
        <h1>Hotspot</h1>
        <h2>To gain internet access, enter your email.</h2>
        <br />
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" autofocus="autofocus" />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit_ok" name="submit_ok" /> <br />
    </form>

<script type="text/javascript">

document.getElementById("submit_ok").addEventListener("click", SendAjax);
    function SendAjax() {
        var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
        console.log(email);
        // Check if fields are empty 
        if (email=="") {
            alert("Please enter your email.");
        }
        // AJAX code to submit form
        else{
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', 'http://router/login', true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                var DONE = 4;
                var OK = 200;
                if (xhr.readyState === DONE){
                    if (xhr.status === OK){
                        var xhr2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        xhr2.open('POST', 'http://server/insertDB.php', true);
                        xhr2.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
                        var useremail = document.getElementById("email").value;

                        xhr2.onreadystatechange = function () {
                            if (xhr2.readyState === DONE){
                                if (xhr2.status === OK){        
                                    location.href = "http://server/redirected.html";
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    xhr2.send("Email="+encodeURIComponent(useremail));
                }
            }
            xhr.send("username=HSuser&password=SimpleUserPassword");
        }
    };

</script>   
</body>
</html>
```

*Current PHP code:*

```
<?php

    require ('connect.php');

    $clean_email = "";
    $cleaner_email = "";


    if(isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email'])){

        //sanitize with filter
        $clean_email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        //sanitize with test_input
        $cleaner_email = test_input($clean_email);
        //validate with filter
        if (filter_var($cleaner_email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
            // email is valid and ready for use
            echo "Email is valid";  
            //Email is a column in the DB
            $stmt = $DB->prepare("INSERT INTO addresses (Email) VALUES (?)");
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $cleaner_email);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();
        } else {
            // email is invalid and should be rejected
            echo "Invalid email, try again";
        } 
    } else {
    echo "Please enter an email";
    }


    function test_input($data) {
      $data = trim($data);
      $data = stripslashes($data);
      $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
      return $data;
    }

    $DB->close();   
?>
```

*Previous HTML/JS code:*

```
function SendAjax() {
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    console.log(email);
    // Check if fields are empty 
    if (email=="") {
        alert("Please enter your email.");
    }
    // AJAX code to submit form
    else{
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', 'http://router/login', true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            var DONE = this.DONE || 4;
            if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE){
                var xhr2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr2.open('POST', 'http://server/insertDB.php', true);
                xhr2.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
                var useremail = document.getElementById("email").value;

                xhr2.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    var DONE = this.DONE || 4;
                    if (xhr2.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                        location.href = "http://server/redirected.html";
                    }
                };
                xhr2.send("Email="+encodeURIComponent(useremail));
            }
        }

        xhr.send("popup=true&username=HSuser&password=SimpleUserPassword");
    }
}
```

Comment: Just as an FYI JQuery does NOT require that you use $. You may change that if needed.

Comment: That is news to me. thanks for the tip. To be fair though, I'm even worse in JQuery then I am in plain ol JS =)

Comment: It is unclear how it is not waiting.... You nested the two calls and it is inside done and 200...

Comment: you might be right =) I'll change the submit to button. Thanks. Will let you know what happens

Comment: Tried it out. Still the same. Console only returns XHR1, but both POST requests are made (to the router and to the server) wtih status 200... So, no change.

Comment: @James I would love to do that, but this is the only way "I know" how to do it. Feel free to leave an Anwser with an example. =)

Comment: Sorry, scrap that - didn't notice that router was different to server

Comment: Dont worry about it.

Comment: Try moving `xhr2.send...` into the `if` block with the rest of the xhr2 setup stuff

Comment: so right before xhr2.onreadystatechange?

Comment: right after that block

Comment: all right. will let you know what happens.

Comment: with this set-up it just sends the POST to the router, It doesn't send it to the server, console log still has XHR1, and it didn't redirect. (I put `xhr2.send` right after `xhr2.onreadystatechange`)

Answer (score 1):

If it makes your life easier (and it WILL), you can put jQuery into no conflict mode.

```
<!-- Putting jQuery into no-conflict mode. -->
<script src="prototype.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>

var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
// $j is now an alias to the jQuery function; creating the new alias is optional.

$j(document).ready(function() {
    $j( "div" ).hide();
});

// The $ variable now has the prototype meaning, which is a shortcut for
// document.getElementById(). mainDiv below is a DOM element, not a jQuery object.
window.onload = function() {
    var mainDiv = $( "main" );
}

</script>
```

https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/

Then you can make your AJAX call, and the stuff that should wait can go in the success function:

```
            $j.ajax({
                url: '/your-form-processing-page-url-here',
                type: 'POST',
                data: yourVariables,
                mimeType: 'multipart/form-data',
                success: function(data, status, jqXHR){
                    alert('Hooray! All is well.');
                    console.log(data);
                    console.log(status);
                    console.log(jqXHR);

                },
                error: function(jqXHR,status,error){
                    // Hopefully we should never reach here
                    console.log(jqXHR);
                    console.log(status);
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Thanks. I might give it a try. The problem is, that Mikrotik (the router) uses $ sign for it's own operations ie. `$(if chap-id)` ... `$(endif)`. I know it's called non-conflict mode, but I would have to give it a try to see if it actually works. Thanks again.

Comment: It should be fine. Just note in my example that jQuery comes second to load.

Comment: All right. I'll give it a try and let you know what I find.

Comment: I'm not using any libraries at all. If I understand this correctly, JQuery has the noConflict option inbuild by default. Prototype is something different all togather, correct?

Comment: well, after I tried this (`var jq = jQuery.noConflict();`), I got an error messagge: Uncought ReferenceError: JQuery is not defined

Comment: i take it you included the jQuery javascript in your `<head>` section?

Comment: I did. it's in the same folder as the html doc. `<script type="text/javascript" href="jquery-3.4.1.min"></script>`